# Error and infinite loop when calling method in parent FXML controller

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have an application that utilizes multiple FXML controllers. In my root controller (CustomController.java) I have loaded an FXML file that calls MainMenuController. I have another controller/fxml-file that is another "view" of the application.

My question is: What would be the best approach to changing the current "view"? My current method is calling the CustomController.swapOut() when a button is clicked in the mainmenu.fxml. But this is causing an error, as it is creating a MainMenuController object and gets stuck in an infinite loop until memory runs out.

Note: I am currently trying to clear the viewableContent pane first, before attempting to load in a new "view"

```
Application structure => tester.java -> CustomController.java
                                                  |
                                                  V
                                        customController.fxml -> MainMenuController.java
                                                                            |
                                                                            V
                                                                       mainmenu.fxml
```

tester.java

```
package task01;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class tester extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        CustomController customController = new CustomController();

        customController.getStylesheets().add("/task01/stylize.css");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(customController,1920,1080));
        stage.setTitle("Seneca ATM Program");
        stage.setWidth(1920);
        stage.setHeight(1080);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

CustomController.java

```
package task01;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomController extends GridPane
{

    @FXML
    private Pane viewableContent;

    public CustomController()
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("customController.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try
        {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void swapOut()
    {
        viewableContent.getChildren().clear();
    }
}
```

customController.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<?import task01.MainMenuController?>
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="CENTER">
    <ImageView fitWidth="229.67" fitHeight="149.67" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
        <Image url="/task01/logo.png"/>
    </ImageView>
    <Pane fx:id="viewableContent" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
        <MainMenuController/>
    </Pane>
</fx:root>
```

MainMenuController.java

```
package task01;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainMenuController extends GridPane
{
    private CustomController customController = new CustomController();

    @FXML
    private VBox buttonSet;
    @FXML
    private HBox buttonSetOne;
    @FXML
    private HBox buttonSetTwo;
    @FXML
    private  Button changePinButton;
    @FXML
    private Button accountInquiryButton;
    @FXML
    private Button withdrawMoneyButton;
    @FXML
    private Button depositMoneyButton;
    @FXML
    private Button balanceInquiryButton;
    @FXML
    private Button createAccountButton;
    @FXML
    private GridPane gridpane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        createAccountButton.setOnAction(event ->
        {
            customController.swapOut();
        });
    }

    public MainMenuController()
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("mainmenu.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try
        {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

mainmenu.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane" alignment="CENTER" vgap="50" hgap="50" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <padding><Insets top="10" bottom="10" left="10" right="10"/></padding>
    <VBox fx:id="buttonSet" spacing="25" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
        <HBox fx:id="buttonSetOne" spacing="25">
            <Button styleClass="menuButton" fx:id="createAccountButton">Create account</Button>
            <Button styleClass="menuButton" fx:id="changePinButton">Change PIN</Button>
            <Button styleClass="menuButton" fx:id="accountInquiryButton">Account Inquiry</Button>
        </HBox>
        <HBox fx:id="buttonSetTwo" spacing="25">
            <Button styleClass="menuButton" fx:id="withdrawMoneyButton">Withdraw Money</Button>
            <Button styleClass="menuButton" fx:id="depositMoneyButton">Deposit Money</Button>
            <Button styleClass="menuButton" fx:id="balanceInquiryButton">Balance Inquiry</Button>
        </HBox>
    </VBox>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: I am confused. All `swapOut()` does is clear the `viewAbleContent` pane. There's no loading going on in that method.

Comment: @Zephyr yes, i am trying to clear the Pane first before trying to load in a new view

But the issue remains, which is interacting with the Parent controller without creating an object and getting infinite loop.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra sorry, but can you elaborate on the naming conventions? the only naming conventions i am aware of are keeping class names capitalized and relevant to the class' purpose

Comment: _keeping class names capitalized_ - good that you know it, now make sure you _apply_ it everywhere in your code :) There are more - which you are applying correctly, btw - simply search for them ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to pass the "parent" controller to the child controller instead of creating a instance in the child controller. (The instance you initialize your field with would be different to the parent instance anyways which would result in non-working code, even if you prevent the stackoverflow somehow.)

In this case you could use the `FXMLLoader` to pass the value like this:

```xml
<fx:root fx:id="rootController" type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="CENTER">
    <ImageView fitWidth="229.67" fitHeight="149.67" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
        <Image url="/task01/logo.png"/>
    </ImageView>
    <Pane fx:id="viewableContent" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
        <MainMenuController customController="$rootController"/> <!-- pass object to setter using fx:id -->
    </Pane>
</fx:root>
```

**MainMenuController**

```
private CustomController customController; //= new CustomController();

public void setCustomController(CustomController customController) {
    this.customController = customController;
}

// required for fxmlloader to identify the type
public CustomController getCustomController() {
    return customController;
}
```

Comment: thanks. your solution worked.

if possible, can you explain more on how `<MainMenuController customController="$rootController">` works?

Comment: If `FXMLLoader` encounters a "normal" attribute that is not used to fill a constructor parameter, it tries to convert the value to the target type determined using the return type of the getter. A string starting with `$` is treated as "instruction too look the object up in the namespace". Objects with a `fx:id` are inserted to the namespace with this key. You could also have used the more elaborate `<MainMenuController><customController><fx:reference source="rootController" /></customController></MainMenuController>`

Comment: See https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution